# how to insert bulk of data into postgres by using nestJS without loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, nestjs

i am beginner in nestJS. how can I insert the bulk of data into Postgres without using a loop. can anybody share a piece of code that will be helpful for me? thanks.

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { Feature } from './feature.entity';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  constructor(@InjectRepository(Feature) private readonly featureRepository: Repository<Feature>){}

  async addData(data: any){
    
    for(let i = 0; i< data.length; i++){
      await this.featureRepository.manager.query('INSERT INTO public.feature(id, name, phone) VALUES ($1, $2, $3)', [data[i].id, data[i].name, data[i].phone])
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: It'd be helpful if you added more details such as how are you currently inserting any data into postgres from your app, are you using any ORM etc? Details along with snippets of existing code would be very helpful in understanding

Comment: yeah, i added a sample of code that I am using. this is not actual code but i am using this  style for coding

Comment: can you help me with a better style of coding without loop. because my application inserts thousands of records into the database at once

Comment: you can generate a string of values first using the for loop, then you can insert all the values at once which should result in a much faster query. For example INSERT INTO table(a, b, c) VALUES (6, 5, 7), (1, 2, 6), (8, 6, 5) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can inject `DataSource` to your service. and use it for saving multiple entities at once.

```js
@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  constructor(@InjectRepository(Feature) private readonly featureRepository: Repository<Feature>, private readonly dataSource: DataSource){}

  async addData(data: any){
    const features: Feature[] = []
    for(let i = 0; i< data.length; i++){
      features.push(this.featureRepository.create({/* put your data here */})
    }
    return await this.dataSource.manager.save(features)
  }
}
```

actually, you don't even need the `featureRepository` you can instantiate `Feature` class and fill its property without needing the `create` helper method.

There is multiple approaches to do it, just read the `typeorm` documentation.